# disnake реакция на сообщение

Tags: python, discord, disnake

Я пытаюсь понять как сделать реакцию на сообщение, но никак не получается, ищу в документации **disnake**, ничего. Одна и таже ошибка:

```python
@bot.slash_command()
async def reaction(inter):
    emoji = ""
    message = await inter.response.send_message("Окей")
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

###### Ошибка:

```console
Ignoring exception in slash command 'reaction':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/ThinWirelessMigration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/slash_core.py", line 730, in invoke
    await call_param_func(self.callback, inter, self.cog, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/ThinWirelessMigration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/params.py", line 1022, in call_param_func
    return await maybe_coroutine(safe_call, function, **kwargs)
  File "/home/runner/ThinWirelessMigration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/utils.py", line 599, in maybe_coroutine
    return await value
  File "main.py", line 194, in reaction
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
    
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/ThinWirelessMigration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/interaction_bot_base.py", line 1353, in process_application_commands
    await app_command.invoke(interaction)
  File "/home/runner/ThinWirelessMigration/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/disnake/ext/commands/slash_core.py", line 739, in invoke
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
disnake.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'add_reaction'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты не можешь ставить реакцию на слеш-команду, ее как таковой нет в чате, из-за чего выдается ошибка, что такое действие невозможно

Comment: Чуть дополню, ошибка про отсутствие метода `.add_reaction` у `message`. Допустимые методы можно через [`dir`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452/8489602) посмотреть.